# Using Agora's Unity SDK, how can I fix black screen issues?

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming, video-capture, agora.io, agora-implementation

Using Agora's Unity SDK, downloaded from the Asset Store, I get a blank view of myself and the incoming remote user's view is also blank.  Why? How do I fix this?